# Escape character in javascript, Replace \" to only "

Tags: javascript, regex, json, extjs, extjs4

I have a json object which will be returned from the server side as follows.

```
{"name":"value which has \" "} for Ex : {"Key":"This Key\" "}
```

when i get this response on the client side it is automatically encoded as , result after stringify

```
 {"Key":"This Key\\\" "}
```

Now i want to replace the `\\\"` to only `\"`  so my UI can show only `This Key"`

Until i tried to do `jsonString.replace(/\\\"/g,'\"');`  but gives output of `This Key\\"`

Kindly help me, i have got it wrong..

Regards,
Punith

Comment: The server response doesn't need any transformations. It's valid JSON.

Comment: What exactly are you doing with the string? Sounds like you're double-escaping somewhere needlessly.

Comment: @jack yes its a valid JSON, but my UI is showing it as THIS KEY\" ..... but i want it as THIS KEY"

Comment: @deceze THIS KEY" is the value stored in Database, on retrieve and kept it in java String its escaped to THIS KEY\" and then when the object is converted to JSON it is now THIS KEY\\\"

Comment: str.replace('\\\\"','\"');  worked.   please leave your comment if there is any better ways.

Comment: If it's valid JSON it needs no transformation. Having said that, you haven't shown exactly how you use the server response.

Comment: @Jack. My original string in database is (THE KEY") but because of java string auto escaping it is escaped to (THE KEY\").. Now after this, my response of JSON string is sent to client side. might be my reponse is again escaped to (THE KEY\\\") and on redering on UI its shown as THE KEY\" ... So i have replaced the string  to only \"

Comment: I think you should fix the server side instead then.

Comment: @Jack Yes, That should be the ideal fix, I tried but did not get through it. I will surely try and post the answer below. If you have any idea on auto escaping in the java string please post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be trying to write a JSON parser out of regular expressions. Don't do that, use an existing one.

```
var data = JSON.parse(string_of_json);
var key = data.Key;
```

Comment: But only reason i refrained from this is i had to download another JS file, and the project we cannot use any opensource library.

Comment: @PunithRaj — `JSON.parse` is built into modern browsers. Extjs (which you appear to be using already) has its own JSON parser.

Answer (score 2):

You can use replace() function:

```
str.replace('\\\\"','\"');
```

It works.

P.S. You have forget a "\"

Comment: Good :)
Check this as the answer ;)